# how to open a listview item on a new page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to display an item on a new page by clicking on the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register `ItemSelected` event handler for you `ListView`.

```
ListView listViewJson = new ListView();
listViewJson.HasUnevenRows = true;
listViewJson.ItemSelected += listViewJson_ItemSelected;
```

In Event Handler, you can get selected item.

```
private void listViewJson_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.SelectedItem;

    // Navigate to new page
    Navigation.PushAsync(new YOUR_PAGE(item));
}
```

And you can develop UI as you want in you new page for displaying a joke.

**UPDATE**

You detail page should be like this. I prepared this very roughly. Please make necessary changes.

```
namespace JokesListView
 {
    public class JokeDetail : ContentPage
    {

        private Joke jk;

       public JokeDetail(Joke j)
       {
          jk = j;

          Display();
       } 

       public void Display()
       {
          try
          {
            Label lblJoke = new Label();
            lblJoke.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;

             lblJoke.Text = jk.joke;

             Content = lblJoke;
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            throw e;
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: Yes, new page you need to check receive value passed from this page.

Comment: check my updated answer for joke display. You need to make necessary changes to code. You also need to take Joke as a class to pass to another page. Let me know if still got any error.

Comment: Please update new code in question so I can look  and suggest you changes.

Comment: Can you help me with an issue?

Comment: I want to display 10 items at first, then start displaying 10 more each time the user scrolls down

Comment: or do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: check these one and implement. If any doubt, ask new question. Do not continue different topic on this thread. https://github.com/shribits/ListViewPagingAndCaching ...........  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#Pull_to_Refresh   ....................... the term is "Pagination" for loading items on scrolling